# How can i center a image and a text in the outer parent

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPPWeZ

I need to make some images and text centralized in the middle of a gray background.

I've tried using `line-height`, `vertical-align`, `padding`, however nothing works.
Can anyone give me a light?

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<section class="main">
  <h2 class="main__title">"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="main__list">
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."

        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="main__item">
        <img class="main__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
        <p class="main__tip">
          "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 730px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
  .main__title {
    font-family: 'gill_sans_std';
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #004c6b;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 25px; }
  .main__list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; }
  .main__item {
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0; }
  .main__tip {
    font-family: 'gill_sans_std';
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 585px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px; }
```

Comment: Your codepen is empty. EDIT: Also, do you want horizontal centering or vertical centering?

Comment: i want center the picture and the text vertically Zac. My codepen is fine here.. can you please check again?

Comment: it was empty.. now there is code :).

Comment: You are linking to codepens 'new pen' page.  Updating your code will not reflect upon that link, ever.  You have to save a pen before you link it. Here is what you want. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOOdRx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix your problem using:
 -`float:left` for image
 - `display: table` for li
 - `display:table-cell` for p

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/g3dcd1cL/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

http://codepen.io/Billy-Purvis/pen/JddGaQ

I added this code.

```
.container {
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

Add in your css:

```
.main__image {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And remove from .main__item the height

```
.main__item {
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
  position: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Then, it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Add those code in your css file:

```
 .main__item img{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```